# Pressure washer adapter for Portland pressuer washer and Sun Joe attachments

Tags: adapter, pressure-washer

I bought a [Portland Pressure Washer](https://www.harborfreight.com/1750-psi-13-gpm-corded-electric-pressure-washer-63254.html) (I think STYDDI connector), not knowing a whole lot about pressure washers. I wanted to clean my gutters, and bought a [Sun Joe kit](https://amzn.to/3AO2NER) (SPX?) to help me use my pressure washer to clean the gutters without having to climb a ladder. I just tried connecting them today for the first time and realized they aren't compatible, although they seem kind of close. Is there any kind of an adapter I can get that will allow me to connect these together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Sun Joe attachment has a proprietary connector for their SPX series of pressure washers.  I do see, however, any number of STYDDI compatible attachments that appear to be very similar to the one you have.

It might be easiest to return the one you have in favor of one that works.  I did not find any adapters to go between STYDDI and SPX which also leads me to believe SPX is proprietary.

Comment: Yeah, that seems likely what I will have to do. Too bad I bought the thing several months ago and likely it is past the return window. Oh well, thanks!

Comment: In that case the good news is that it wasn't all that expensive.